# Apache detect redirect with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

in my vhost.conf file, I am redirecting all requests to custom location:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www\.tokk\.sk/$1    [L,R=302]
```

And I'am using custom error document:

```
ErrorDocument 302 /redirect.py
```

I had to add following rule to exclude redirect.py from actual redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/redirect\.py$
RewriteRule ^  -    [L]
```

Now user can directly access this file (redirect.py) from his browser. But I want ALL requests to be redirected. So such user access to this redirect.py should be also redirected :)

So in rule above, I tried to add something like

```
RewriteCond %{REDIRECT_STATUS}  ^302$
```

But it's not working. Can I somehow detect, that processing request isn't from user, but was generated by RewriteRule?

Comment: Starting from Apache 2.3, there should be flag END, which might solve this problem:
[http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved in redirect.py script.
When `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/redirect\.py$` is hit, in my CGI script environment variable **REDIRECT_STATUS** is set. So when the variable is not set, then the request come directly from user. And then the redirection is done by script.